# Angular6 ServiceWorker dont cache all files

Tags: angular6, angular-service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I generated a clean Angular6 Project and use `ng add @angular/pwa` i get this `ngsw-config.json`:

```
{
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/index.html",
                    "/*.css",
                    "/*.js"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/assets/**"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

There is the whole assets folder marked for "Service Worker Caching" But the Sad reality show that this isnt real:

[image]

The 3 Graphic files i use ( `header-bg.jpg`, `list-border-red.svg` & `list-border-green.svg` ) Are marked as "from ServiceWorker" But when i create a App on my Smartphone, and disconnect the Internet connection and open the App, is only `header-bg.jpg` available. but `list-border-red.svg` & `list-border-green.svg` are not available offline.

Also shows the graphic thas 2 favicons are loaded from "Disc Cache" and one from the ftp... The files are also in the assets folder, why they are not cached fro mServiceWorker? Is the ServiceWorker stuff maybe bugged in Chrome?

The App is allready Online and can be found here: https://expense-calculator.com/ Just open and make your own tests if you need this to reproduce my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your service worker code looks good and is registered perfectly to serve the files in offline just as you have expected it to work. I've checked in Chrome with Airplane mode on. All files including .svg files loaded from cache.

Please retry.

Comment: Thank you alot for your time! I checked it again, and i still got the same result as on my screenshot below. Everything is cached fine, except the `favicon.ico` & `favicon-32x32.png`. I do not understand where the difference between the `favicon-32x32` and the `favicon-16x16` is. Because the `favicon-16x16` is cached clean and well.

Comment: I also wonder about the fact, that the fonts are 2 times inside the dist folder: https://i.imgur.com/IzFToUR.png

Comment: What u mean by the same result ? I do not see any screenshot. Attach a new screenshot of network tab in offline mode and highlight all the files that are not loading. Make sure you do hard reload once.

Comment: I don't need to attach any new Screenshot. Because my Network Tab Looks exactly Like in the First Screenshot. :) I also tryed in inkognito Tab. Still Same.

Comment: Please read the I’ve asked for a screenshot of offline mode with files failing highlighted...which is not what you have provided... nor you have provided the list of files which fails. In one place you have mentioned on svg  and one place icons. If this is how u help us to help you, good luck with it.